# Is there any way to have Gmail folders show total unread count (including subfolders)

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I sometimes miss unread emails because they are sitting in sub folders

Let's say I have a folder called **Trips** with 3 sub folders called, **Florida, Boston, Washington** respectively.

If **Florida** has one unread mail and **Boston** has two unread mails, I would like **Trips** to show `3` unread.  By default it seems like it shows `0` because there are no unread mails in the actual **Trips** folders (not counting sub folders).

Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: It's important to note that Gmail uses labels, not folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions that might help:

1. Unread mail folders still appear in **BOLD** (Edit: if you keep them collapsed), so you should see **Trips** as opposed to Trips (even though there won't be a message count).
2. In [Gmail Label Settings](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/labels) you can choose to show them in the left menu if they contain unread messages. You could set the option to `show if unread` (so the label will only appear on the left if there are unread messages).
3. (I didn't test this) I think you can choose three *distinct* labels, e.g., Boston, Florida, Trips (without nesting them). Make sure all Boston and Florida emails are also tagged Trips (a filter could do this?). This might get you the message count, but it is probably not easy to make sure the messages are consistently labeled.

Comment: Trips is NOT bold if the only unread messages are in subfolders so #1 above is not correct.

Comment: @leora See my edit about "keeping them collapsed" (if you open the triangle to see subfolders, the bold disappears).

Comment: Option 2 has saved my life - this way, you don't actually NEED sub-labels, just check each label to this option, and they pop up 'like magic' when you have emails. Perfect solution for me.

Comment: @DrWhodini hope you upvoted then! :-)